# How to fix "Input stream not found at : net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml" error?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have created a java desktop application using netbeans7.4. I used ireport 5.6.0 for reporting purpose. I created custom font via font extention. **All these are perfectly working when I run the application within/outside (from dist folder) the IDE**.

Now when I compile everything into one jar (Run Target>Other Targets>Package-for-store), I got following error to run the file. **(I need to compile to one jar because i want to create an installer)**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:124)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:89)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:104)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:62)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:108)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:668)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:984)
at cop.JRep.PrintActionPerformed(JRep.java:845)
at cop.JRep.access$1300(JRep.java:55)
at cop.JRep$14.actionPerformed(JRep.java:474)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
at cop.JRep.jButton3ActionPerformed(JRep.java:797)
at cop.JRep.access$700(JRep.java:55)
at cop.JRep$8.actionPerformed(JRep.java:324)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Input stream not found at : net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:188)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:110)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Input stream not found at : net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getInputStreamFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:159)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:183)
    ... 59 more
```

Every thing is working fine(database, application) **except Ireport parts**. Can any one help me with this problem. Thanks in advance to all of you for providing me your support.

Can anybody tell me whether the following code is perfect? I used this code to generate a single jar file.

```
<target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="myProject"/>
    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>
    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by [old jasperreports](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/542314/problem-fonts-input-stream-not-found-netsfjasperreportsfontsfontsxml) ,

Use  jasperreports.5.0.0.jar or higher version which includes your missing fonts.xml.

Comment: My ireport version is 5.6.0.

Comment: What is your jasperreports version?

Comment: Latest is jasperreports-6.5.0.jar

Comment: thanks I will download and try? thanks for your help.